# How to ignore different combinations in preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, match

For example's sake let's look at this example:

```
target="_blank">EXTRACT THIS</a>
```

I want to extract that text that is a hyperlink. I am using the following code:

```
preg_match("/target=\"_blank\">(.*)<\/a>/", $content, $result);
```

The problem is that there can be overlapping combinations like:

```
<a href="LINK" target="_blank">TEXT</a> <a href="LINK_2" target="_blank">TEXT_2</a>
```

and this rule would also return:

```
TEXT</a> <a href="LINK_2" target="_blank">TEXT_2
```

which I obviously don't want.

The question is: how to avoid extracting overlaps like these?

Comment: Use a HTML parser. Regexes are not suitable to parse HTML.

Comment: Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your RE:

```
(.*)
```

Says to grab everything.  The .* is known as greedy and will grab everything it can.
There are two solutions to this.

One:

```
(.*?)
```

The non-greedy operation of .*

Two:

```
([^<]*)
```

Simply match anything that is not a < character.  This is faster than .*?

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.